# CRF implementation with Python API that allows a CRF model to be trained multithreadedly

Tags: python, natural-language, software, conditional-random-field

I am looking for a conditional random field (CRF) implementation with a Python API that allows a CRF model to be trained multithreadedly.

I currently use [pyCRFsuite](https://github.com/jakevdp/pyCRFsuite), which works great except that CRF models cannot be trained with more than one threads. I use it for natural language processing purposes.

Ideally it should work on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/adsva/python-wapiti can use multiple threads at training time.

With crfsuite you can still do hyperparameter search in parallel, see e.g. an example at https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/blob/master/docs/CoNLL2002.ipynb